# как сказать грамотно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сейчас модным стало употребление слова "человек" в такой например форме "В Колумбии в результате схода оползня погибли сотни человек"
Мне это выражение очень режет слух.
По моему правильнее сказать "В Колумбии в результате схода оползня погибли сотни людей"
Какой вариант соответствует грамотной речи?

Answer (score 1):

**Соотношение форм "человек ― люди" довольно сложная, и в этой теме рассматриваются различные варианты.**

Существительное "человек" не имеет  мн. числа, **но форма  "человек" может иметь значение Р.п. мн. числа: 5 человек**, так как воспринимается как сущ. м.р. с нулевым окончанием во мн.числе.

Эта форма **успешно конкурирует** с формой "людей" в счетных оборотах, например:  пять незнакомых **человек** и пять незнакомых **людей** – варианты при наличии определения, но: пять **человек** (нет определения).

(Также обратим внимание на то, что сто ― это числительное, а сотня ― существительное с числовым значением "сто").

**Сравним частотность выражений в Нацкорпусе:** [сотни людей](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EE%F2%ED%E8+%EB%FE%E4%E5%E9) и [сотни человек](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EE%F2%ED%E8+%F7%E5%EB%EE%E2%E5%EA) (500:100), сотня людей и сотня человек (13:10), сто людей и сто человек (1:300).

**Как можно видеть, сочетание "сотни человек" вполне приемлемо на слух, да  и грамматике не противоречит,** тем более что "сто людей" практически вообще не употребляется (то есть форма "человек" в ряде случаев способна потеснить форму "людей").